# Getting error posting calendar events

Tags: office365, office365api

Using the Unified API call 
`POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{tenant}/groups('{groupId}')/events`

to add calendar events to a group. I'm intermittently getting the following error:

> An unexpected 'PrimitiveValue' node was found when reading from the
>   JSON reader. A 'StartObject' node was expected.

My Json object looks to match what is provided in the online documentation.  Has anyone seen this error and, if so, do you have a resolution?

Comment: Hi Rob, can you provide your JSON that you are using? This error implies there might be some small syntax error. Another good thing you can try first a "GET" on the same object, and then check out the syntax used there, and then try a "POST" by simply modifying this.

Comment: Shawn - Actually did some more research and it looks like the calendar for the groups we are having issues with are corrupted.  Did a Get on https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}/{tenant}/groups('{groupId}')/calendar/events plugging in various groupid's.  For most groups we received either a populated or empty JSON return.  For the groups with issues the Get returned a JSON parsing error.  So it appears to be an issue with the calendar for the group.

Comment: Do you know how these might have gotten corrupted from your perspective? Are you able to fix these by deleting the calendar and re-adding it?

Comment: Shawn - Not sure how they could have gotten corrupted.  They were intermittent.  We tried deleing the group and then reading it but still received the issue.  We had some old pre-API code that we tried using again and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

We released an update that is causing issues on /event calls for those users or group mailboxes that have not been updated to the latest build. This issue should resolve as soon the deployment rollout is complete.
More information on: http://dev.office.com/blogs/Update-3-on-Office-365-unified-API

Comment: Yina - Is there an ETA on when the rollout will be?

Comment: That particular build was completed 11/17